# execute ansible loop according to count value.count=3 should take only 3 values rest it shouldnot execute

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to execute an ansible playbook according to the count value passed. If I pass a count value of 3 then the loop should take only 3 values present in the loop.

Below is my playbook:

```
---
- name: Decommission Tenant virtual machine
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
       VMType: "{{VMType}}"
  vars_files:
    - vault.yml
  tasks:
    - name: "Deleting Tenant VM after knowing the VM Status as Powered OFF"
      vmware_guest:
        hostname: "{{item.hostname1}}"
        username: "{{ vault_username }}"
        password: "{{ vault_pass }}"
        validate_certs: no
        name: "{{item.name1}}"
        state: absent
      count: 3
      loop:
        - { hostname1: "{{v_hostname1}}", name1: "{{VMName1}}" }
        - { hostname1: "{{v_hostname2}}", name1: "{{VMName2}}" }
        - { hostname1: "{{v_hostname3}}", name1: "{{VMName3}}" }
        - { hostname1: "{{v_hostname4}}", name1: "{{VMName4}}" }
        - { hostname1: "{{v_hostname5}}", name1: "{{VMName5}}" }
      when: VMType == "tenant"
```

Comment: I think one possible way is to use a filter to limit the number of items you hand over to the loop e.g: {{ [0,2]|map('extract', ['x','y','z'])|list }}

Comment: Max 5 entries is mandatory.if user provide only 2 vm names then 2 items it should iterate and if user provides 3 vm names then it should iterate 3 times.max entries are 5.so kept 5 values

Comment: Cena, instead of answering to comments in the comments, please update the original question. Also look to the page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve the question to give better context of the problem